# Can we say a dependency preserving decomposition of a relation is lossless decomposition..?

Tags: database, normalization, decomposition

I want to ask if a decomposition preserves dependency then will it always be a loss less decomposition...?

Suppose I have a relation R and I have decomposed this table in two tables R1 and R2 so that
R1 and R2 preserves all the dependency present in R.
So will this decomposition be a lossless or it can't be answered..?

Please guide me.Thanks.

Comment: No, it is not always true ...